# from local storage I am not getting data in input tags

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am storing data in local storage. But when I am trying to retrieve the data from local storage, data is not coming in input tags. When the page changes, that time it should come. Please help me out. What is the mistake in the code?

**in HTML5:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form novalidate id="setting_form">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textusername1">Username</label>
                <input name="textusername1" id="textusername1" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="textpassword1">Password</label>
                <input name="textpassword1" id="textpassword1" value="" type="text">
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">                    
                <div data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" id="button1" onclick="callConnection();">Update</div>
            </div> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>  

<div data-rol2="page" id="show">
    <div data-role="content" id="content2">
        <form novalidate id="setting_form1">
            <label for="un">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="un" class="field" id="un" value="">

            <label for="pw">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="pw"  class="field" id="pw" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**In jQuery:**

```
$(document).unbind('pageinit').bind('pageinit', function () {              
    $("#show").on("pageshow", function (event) {
        $("#un").text(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        $("#pw").text(localStorage.getItem("pass"));
    });
});

function callConnection(){
    localStorage.setItem("user", $("#textusername1").val());
    localStorage.setItem("pass", $("#textpassword1").val());

    if (localStorage.getItem("user") == "" && localStorage.getItem("pass") == "") {
        alert("enter the username and password");
    }
    else {
        $.mobile.changePage("#show");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change and input value you must use `val`, so change:

```
$("#un").text(localStorage.getItem("user"));
$("#pw").text(localStorage.getItem("pass"));
```

to:

```
$("#un").val(localStorage.getItem("user"));
$("#pw").val(localStorage.getItem("pass"));
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rg3n6/

Comment: thanx for the help now i m getting the answer